# Can I set the text color when syntax is off?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, colorscheme

I want `syntax off` but I want to pick a different text color.  Do I have to find the relevant setting in my color scheme? Or is there something I can just put in `.vimrc`?

```
set termguicolors
colorscheme gruvbox
let g:gruvbox_contrast_dark = 'hard'

syntax on
highlight Normal guifg=#ff6000
```

Comment: You could _try_ the `Normal` highlight group

Comment: @D.BenKnoble that works, but only if I manually source my `.vimrc` each time I open vim... thoughts?

Comment: How are you modifying it? I would probably use an autocommand on the ColorScheme event (defined before running `:colorscheme` obviously)

Comment: Modified answer with relevant lines!